# Encountered a StorageException while trying to fetch the diagnostic events

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-storage-account, azure-functions-runtime

Out of nowhere started seeing this error when opened function apps, Application is working though.

```
Unable to retrieve diagnostics and error information for your function app. 
Encountered a StorageException while trying to fetch the diagnostic events. 
Please make sure the connection string in the app setting "AzureWebJobsStorage" has the permissions to access Azure Table Storage
```

Storage account network access is set to "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses". Even with this settings there was no error before.

but now the above error message is gone only when changed to "Enabled from all networks".

Recently updated functionapp to dotnet 6.0 and v4 runtime even after, there was no error. Not sure if this has anything to do with this.

How do I fix for this?

Comment: Started seeing the same issue in one of my Azure Functions. Did you find a fix meanwhile?

Comment: not yet @Alex..

Comment: Same issue here! Our existing Azure Functions do have the warning but are still running fine (and KUDU is accessible). I am trying to deploy a new one, which fails, because KUDU is unavailable due to this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was caused by a platform level alert raised by a diagnostic component, and although it had no impact on the production workloads, the verbiage wasn't clear and the level misleading. The event has been disabled and you should no longer see this come up.

To expand, this error was reported by the control plane for the diagnostic component, which is meant to surface diagnostic events raised by production components to the portal, but not involved in any production workload flow and had no impact on the App's functionality.

Comment: looks good now ..

Answer (score 3):

We noticed the same issue in several of our functionapps. We also have configured the functionapp to be able to access the storage account via a subnet in a vnet, which worked fine until a few days ago. The functionapp itself is still working as intended, but it started showing  this message a few days ago. As a test we did 'Enable from all networks' on the storage account, which resolved the warning message. I suspect there is some other service besides the functionapp which needs access to the storage account to read the functionapp diagnostic information. If I would know which service we could grant it access to the storage account without needing to 'Enable from all networks'

Answer (score 2):

I raised a support ticket with Microsoft regarding this issue and was told that there seems to be a platform issue for App Services in West Europe region and they are currently investigating.

Comment: I did the same. The Azure support engineer responded and acknowledged that there is an issue on Microsoft's side and that they're looking into it.